# Colorize legend value labels to match the colors of the points of the scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do you colorize the values of the legend value labels (currently in gray) to match exactly the colors of the points of the scatter plot?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, col=cut)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To color the legend text labels according to the points I would suggest to use a named color vector and some styling via HTML/CSS using `ggtext` inside a `scale_color_manual`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

pal_viridis5 <- scales::viridis_pal()(5)
names(pal_viridis5) <- levels(diamonds$cut)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price, col = cut)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = pal_viridis5,
    labels = ~ paste0("<span style='color: ", pal_viridis5[.x], "'>", .x, "</span>")
  ) +
  theme(legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]